# How do I use a serial number in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm looking for something like this (below is C)

```
void MyFunction() {
    //Do work
    static int serial;
    ++serial;
    printf("Function run #%d\n", serial);
    //Do more work
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As *Ice Giant* mentions in their answer, you can use `static mut` to solve this. However, it is unsafe for a good reason: if you use it, you are responsible for making sure that the code is thread safe.

It's very easy to misuse and introduce unsound code and undefined behavior into your Rust program, so what I would recommend that you do instead is to use a type that provides safe interior mutability, such as  [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html), or in the case of integers, atomics like [`AtomicU32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicU32.html):

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering};

fn my_function() {
    // NOTE: AtomicU32 has safe interior mutability, so we don't need `mut` here
    static SERIAL: AtomicU32 = AtomicU32::new(0);

    // fetch and increment SERIAL in a single atomic operation
    let serial = SERIAL.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);

    // do something with `serial`...
    println!("function run #{}", serial);
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f1fe03fbfd9cca02af413e5d18176656)

Because this program does not contain any unsafe code, we can be certain that the program does not contain the same [data race](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/races.html) bugs that can be caused by naïve use of `static mut` (or the equivalent use of `static` in the C code).

Comment: Its mostly for debugging. And I rather dislike needing to come up with unique serial names (I tend to print multiple functions) I like simply having it within the function. I guess C++ spoiled me

Comment: @EricStotch You can have `SERIAL` inside the function as well, if you want: [Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8b07460dcc3b7bf1e5f7b2029f8f911) (Updated the answer to do this to match your C code better.)